# Vim motion to jump-to-character and change after it

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm looking for a motion that will combine the following commands: `f=lC` (as in, I'm on a line and I want to change everything to the right of the `=`).

If we have this: `v_ar something = 123;` then after executing `f=lC` we'd be left with `var something =_`, with the cursor at the position of `_`.

Is there a native vim motion for this? I couldn't find any, and couldn't find one in the [targets.vim](https://github.com/wellle/targets.vim) plugin either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: well, you can define you own key map in such a case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a  normal map if that action is repeated a  lot and do it
in  one stroke;  as mentioned  in other  answers. Or  you can  create an
operator map, which  might be more appropriate, in my  opinion.
From `:h omap-info`:

> Operator-pending mappings  can be  used to  define a  movement command
>   that can be used with any  operator. Simple example: `:omap { w` makes
>   `y{` work like `yw` and `d{` like `dw`.

As you can see, this allows you  to use your map with existing commands.
As an example to your case:

```
onoremap <silent> = :<C-U>normal! 0f=lv$h
```

This creates a  motion (`=`) that when activated clears  the range (with
`<C-U`>) and  selects a  portion of the  text that is  sent back  to the
original command.  The selection  is what  is at the  left of  the first
equal sign (`0f=l`) until  the end of the line (`$h`).  Note that `h` is
used to deselect the newline character selected by the `$` mark.

You can then use `d=` or `c=` to do what you want.

Creating a  command that *asks* to  which character you need  to find is
also possible,  but more complex.  Create more of these  combinations in
your *.vimrc* if  you think they are useful. This  is not "polluting" by
any means, if you judge it is used often enough.

Comment: Thank you for providing examples and the correct terminology to search in the docs. Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just make a mapping:

```
:nnoremap s f=lC
```

Now just pressing `s` does the trick (of course you can use any other letter, `s` is just one I rarely use).

Comment: Thank you. How would you make said new normal mode remap take a character argument, like `f` does? Part of the reason I'm looking for a native motion is to be able to specify targets other than `=`, the other part being to avoid polluting the keymap-space with more personal combos.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gn` command. This moves to the next search match, so in your case first search for your pattern, e.g. `/=\zs.*` and then type `cgn` and you should be left with `var something =` Now you can repeat the process pressing `.`

Note, the `gn` was introduced with Vim 7.4